# How-to add cpufreq indicator to system tray

Tags: 11.10, indicator, cpufreq

I installed `cpufreq` indicator from the ppa:artfwo/ppa repository. The cpufreq started and I see it by system monitor but I can't see him in system tray. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean in the indicator area - or are you talking about the gnome-shell system tray?

Comment: @fossfreedom Yes. I mean the indicator area. Sorry.

Comment: Can you confirm that you actually installed the correct package? `sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq` - what errors if any do you get if you run `indicator-cpufreq` from the command line?

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem. This was a bug with the Faenza icon theme. https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq/+bug/772084

Comment: This is a bug as @falcon stated.

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq/+bug/772084) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score -1):

An example from my machine, you can add/remove things from or to it.
Terminal:
`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'parcellite', 'Skype', 'hp-systray']"`

Comment: This is dangerous! If the user just picks up this command and types it to a terminal he might loose what configurations he has at the moment. You should make an answer to specifically to his request, in his case he wants `cpufreq` white-listed but that does not mean that your config will work on his system. There is room for improving this but its on the right path, try to make it better.

Comment: I have tried it (add 'indicator-cpufreq' or 'cpufreq') but it doesn't work.

Comment: afaik you have to start nautilus again, with:`nautilus -q` and `nautilus` via the terminal. Did you try that?

Comment: @leoquant I did reboot.

Comment: try this thread on ubuntuforums: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1742774.html if you have further questions please let me know.

Comment: @leoquant Thank you. I solved this problem. This was a bug with the Faenza icon theme. https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq/+bug/772084